# Get current OverlayItem being drawn

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay, overlayitem

I want to be able to get some reference to the curent object being drawn

```
@Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,boolean shadow) {
            //Log.i("DRAW","MARKER");
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
        }
```

Above is my draw method and I want to extend the draw method to write the title underneath each item for example.  This would require the .getTitle() method from the OverlayItem.  Possibly some tracking of objects outside of this method but not sure where to put it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar.
I've added some markers to a `MapView` and afterwards connecting them with a line.

I have a class `LineOverlay` which extends `Overlay`.
In the constructor it gets the list of items to be connected by lines.

Something like:

```
public LineOverlay(ItemizedOverlay<? extends OverlayItem> itemizedOverlay, int lineColor) {
    mItemizedOverlay = itemizedOverlay;
    colorRGB = lineColor;
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setColor(colorRGB);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(LINE_WIDTH);
}
```

and then on the `onDraw()` I do this:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    if ( mItemizedOverlay.size() == 0 || mItemizedOverlay.size() == 1 )
        return;

    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

    int i = 0;

    while( i < mItemizedOverlay.size() - 1 ){
        OverlayItem begin = mItemizedOverlay.getItem(i);
        OverlayItem end = mItemizedOverlay.getItem(i+1);
        paintLineBetweenStations(begin,end,projection,canvas);
        i++;
    }

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
}

private void paintLineBetweenStations(OverlayItem from, OverlayItem to, Projection projection, Canvas canvas){
    GeoPoint bPoint = from.getPoint();
    GeoPoint ePoint = to.getPoint();

    Point bPixel = projection.toPixels(bPoint, null);
    Point ePixel = projection.toPixels(ePoint, null);

    canvas.drawLine(bPixel.x, bPixel.y, ePixel.x, ePixel.y, mPaint);
}
```

In your case you can do something similar creating a `SubtitleOverlay` which extends `Overlay` that receives all items in the constructor and then on the `draw` method create a subtitle in the correct position.

Comment: I have seen this example quite a lot and can see how this would draw a line between the points.  I cannot see how you would use the getTitle and retrieve the name to write that and more importantly at the correct point.

Comment: @Lee Armstrong Inside the draw method you can call: `mItemizedOverlay.getItem(i).getTitle()` to get the title. The position where to draw can be done with the information of `.getPoint()` and `projection.toPixels`.

Comment: thanks.  I see what you mean now.  Take a look at this... http://www.john-ambler.com/ais/google.html How would I go about drawing those types of Polylines that are not connected?

Comment: @Lee Armstrong: Use `canvas.drawLine` between your marker x,y and the end of the line x,y